# How do I get a Canon Lide 110 working?

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

Canon Lide 110 worked fine with ubuntu 11.04.

When I upgraded to 12.04 (unfortunately) it doesn't work anymore.

Is there anything that can be done so I can use my very nice scanner again?

Comment: Wait, what does not work anymore? The printer or the scanner? And define: does not work.

Comment: If people still have this problem, they may find [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon) useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. Something changed between 11.10 and 12.04 concerning the connection between SAMBA and CUPS

Basically, until it gets fixed, you have to specify the printer manually.

Under XP and Vista, connect using (Add printer dialog, network printer):

```
http://ip-address-of-server:631/printers/PrinterName
```

Under Win7, connect using:

```
\\ServerName\PrinterName
```

This is a high priority confirmed bug. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971847 etc.